# 3D plot and 3D histogram subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

```py
    import numpy as np
    import math
    from pylab import cm,imshow,colorbar,title,show
    import pylab as pyl

    from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    #Parameters
    N = 10**2                        #Step of discretization
 
    # Cost function
    T = np.linspace(0,1,N, False) #Discretization of [0,1]
    S = np.linspace(1,2,N,False) #Discretization of [1,2]
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(T,S)
    C = (X-Y)**2                    #Matrix of c[i,j]=(xi-yj)²

    def Sinkhorn(M, r, c, lam):
    """
    Computes the optimal transport matrix and Slinkhorn distance using the
    Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm

    Inputs:
        - M : cost matrix (n x m)
        - r : vector of marginals (n, )
        - c : vector of marginals (m, )
        - lam : strength of the entropic regularization
        - arret : convergence parameter

    Outputs:
        - P : optimal transport matrix (n x m)
        - dist : Sinkhorn distance
    """

    # Uniform measure over [0;1]
    uni1 = np.ones(N)

    # Uniform measure over [1;2]
    uni2 = np.ones(N)

    n = 1000

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    # I'm going to compute a matrix which is a approximation of a probability over R^{2}
    Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, uni1, uni2, 1/10**4)
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Gamma_star)
    plt.title("Gamma bar 1/{} entre une uniforme([0;1]) et uniforme([1;2])".format(1/10**4))    
    plt.show()
```

[image: Output of my code]

My question : Gamma bar converge to a measure I would like to investigate so I would like to print subplot, something like this : (of course it didn't work and it's just to tell you what is on my mind)

```
    for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(2,2,i+1) 
        Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, uni1, uni2, 1/10**i)
        ax.scatter(X, Y, Gamma_star)
        plt.title("Gamma bar 1/{} between uniform([0;1]) and uniform([1;2])".format(1/10**i))    
    plt.plot()
```

I also would like to plot (subplot in the very same way) 3D histogram with X,Y and Z = Gamma_bar like this one :

[image: Histogram3D]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the first part (subplot the graph), here's my solution :

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1, projection='3d')
    Gamma_star, tqui = Sinkhorn(C, uni1, uni2, 1/10**i)
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Gamma_star)
    plt.title("Gamma bar 1/{} entre une uniforme([0;1]) et uniforme([1;2])".format(1/10**i))

plt.show()
```

And the result : [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbASQ.png)

Do you have any idea to improve my plot ? 
Maybe add colors, maybe change the parameters because all the plots look like the same, ...
Any help is welcome :).

For exemple I find this color pretty cool :

[Colorfull plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QVUk.png)

Anyway, now I'm going to focus on the histogram3D subplot.